# PayPal API - Processing both one time payment and a recurring payment in a single checkout using PayFlow Pro

Tags: php, paypal, payflowpro

I'm setting up a shopping cart where there are one time paid products and a recurring payment product (subscription). **A buyer can select both and proceed to PayPal checkout**. **This must be done with a single checkout**. Please explain me how to achieve this using **PayPal PayFlow Pro API**. I'm coding with PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour, re-formulate your question and show us what have you done already and what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make two separate calls to the PayFlow API (one to process the one-time payment for the paid products, and another to create the recurring profile), or you could just make a single call to create a recurring profile and include the OPTIONALTRX.  When you include that you can set any amount you want to be processed immediately as a one-time payment when the profile gets created.

These documents will greatly help you with the flow of everything.

- [PayFlow Developer Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf)
- [PayFlow Recurring Billing Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf)

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the individual PayFlow calls very quick and easy for you.  It comes with a PayFlowTransaction.php sample that is fully functional.  All you would have to do is add/adjust parameters in that sample to match the calls you need to make based on the information in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your detailed and clear explanation. This will help me to fix the issue. Thanks again!